# Using regex to replace parameters in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to iterate through elements of a struct, look for strings that include the format `{...}`, and replace them with a corresponding string from a hash. This is the data I'm using:

```
Request = Struct.new(:method, :url, :user, :password)
request = Request.new
request.user = "{user} {name}"
request.password = "{password}"
parameters = {"user" => "first", "name" => "last", "password" => "secret"}
```

This is attempt 1:

```
request.each do |value|
  value.gsub!(/{(.+?)}/, parameters["\1"])
end
```

In this attempt, `parameters["\1"] == nil`.

Attempt 2:

```
request.each do |value|
  value.scan(/{(.+?)}/) do |match|
    value.gsub!(/{(.+?)}/, parameters[match[0]])
  end
end
```

This results in `request.user == "first first"`. Trying `parameters[match]` results in `nil`.

Can anyone assist solving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of your attempt will work because arguments of `gsub!` are evaluated prior to the call of `gsub!`. `parameters[...]` will be evaluated prior to replacement, so it has no way to reflect the match. In addition, `"\1"` will not be replaced by the first capture even if that string was the direct argument of `gsub!`. You need to escape the escape character like `"\\1`". To make it work, you need to give a block to `gsub!`.

But instead of doing that, try to use what already is there. You should use string format `%{}` and use symbols for the hash.

```
request.user = "%{user} %{name}"
request.password = "%{password}"
parameters = {user: "first", name: "last", password: "secret"}
request.each do |value|
  value.replace(value % parameters)
end
```

Comment: Hi @sawa, your answer is great, but can you please explain the magic behind `value % parameters`. I have not seen the % operator used in this way before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsub` with a block.

```
request.each do |e|
  e.gsub!(/{.+?}/) { |m| parameters[m[1...-1]] } if e
end
```